# set transparent panel on top of canvas

Tags: java, user-interface, transparency, jpanel

I have a canvas and I want when mouse entered it, some transparent Jpanel containing some components displayed on top of my canvas. I used JlayeredPane for this; but as you see in following example when I want to display transparent panel on top of canvas, by adding it to jLayeredPane on upper layer, It's background is shown as color of the panel that is under canvas.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(200 , 200);
JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
frame.setContentPane(layeredPane);
JPanel canvasPanel = new JPanel();
canvasPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout()); 
canvasPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
canvasPanel.add(canvas);
layeredPane.add(canvasPanel , JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
canvasPanel.setSize(200 , 200);

JPanel transparentPanel = new JPanel();
transparentPanel.setSize(100 , 100);
transparentPanel .setOpaque(false);
transparentPanel.add(new JButton("button"));

layeredPane.add(transparentPanel , JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);

frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

how can I show transparent panel on canvas such that, It's background seems as canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem, when I ran the code as is it resulted in the button on top of a red square on a black background

If not working for you, try setting the `transparentPanel` background color to red (same as `canvasPanel`)

Although this probably wouldn't work for non solid backgrouds